# How read the next value in the same line?

Tags: javascript

I want to read the value "-2.5" in variable "x1", and the value "0.4" in other variable called "y1". And the same for the line below: read "12.1" in a variable "x2" and read "7.3" in a variable "y2"

```
var lines = [
    "-2.5 0.4", 
    "12.1 7.3"
];
```

```
var x1 = parseFloat(lines[0]);
var y1 = jQuery(x1).next();
var x2 = parseFloat(lines[1]);
var y2 = jQuery(x2).next();

console.log(x1);
console.log(y1);
console.log(x2);
console.log(y2);
```

[this is the problem i'm solving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tc18G.png)
[and the code i've made so far, but not accepting "Wrong Answer 85%"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW7nM.png)

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: Have you actually loaded `jquery` in your page?

Comment: I think the problem i'm solving doesn't allow this, is there any other way to do this without using jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error can be solved by investigating whether Jquery is loaded or not, but it won't give you the correct result with your current code.

You can do this:

```js
var lines = [
    "-2.5 0.4", 
    "12.1 7.3"
];
var lineParts = lines[0].split(" ");
var x1 = parseFloat(lineParts[0]);
var y1 = parseFloat(lineParts[1]);

lineParts = lines[1].split(" ");
var x2 = parseFloat(lineParts[0]);
var y2 = parseFloat(lineParts[1]);

console.log(x1, y1, x2, y2);
```

Comment: That's great. I would advise you to learn more about jQuery, as it is mostly suited for DOM related changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can have a look over this solution for your reference, hope this help

```js
var lines = [
  "-2.5 0.4",
  "12.1 7.3"
];

// This will convert a string into an array seperated by space (" ")
const generatePosition = string => string.split(" ");

// This will map all our initial values and change them into a full array
const pos = lines.map(string => generatePosition(string));
console.log(pos);

// From now you can freely access the variable the way you want, this is just for sample demo
const a = pos[0][0];
const b = pos[0][1];
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you reformat your `lines` array so that each value is in its own element? That would make it easier to access each element. Like this:

```
var lines = [
    Array("-2.5","0.4"), 
    Array("12.1","7.3")
];
```

Then you could access the values this way:

```
var x1 = parseFloat(lines[0][0]);
var y1 = parseFloat(lines[0][1]);
var x2 = parseFloat(lines[1][0]);
var y2 = parseFloat(lines[1][1]);
```